# unable to use apt or apt-get with the error message

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt-get

I am using WSL on Windows. I am unable to use

```
apt
```

or

```
apt-get
```

Here is the error message I have when I try to use apt or apt-get.

```
~$ apt
apt: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-private.so.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way I can make it work again? I do not want to re-install WSL just because of this issue.

Comment: Im am also suddenly having the same error, WSL on windows 10.  Not sure what happened

Answer (score 3):

Ok at first find out what is your distribution. 
In my case:

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Then [visit](https://pkgs.org/download/apt) and download ".deb" file to your PC accordingly:

Next run command `sudo dpkg -i <XYZ>.deb` . In my case:

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.6.1_amd64.deb
```

Then you just need to do:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

Hope that helped ;)

Comment: same error came on `apt --fix-broken install` :(